# Android: is there any tool for profiling native code?

Tags: android-ndk, profiling

I have only found one profiling tool - http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/. Wasn't able to get it working so far, so I wonder if there are other tools available.
I need to profile on a physical device, as my application doesn't even work on emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not easy to make the Android-NDK profiler work. You need to follow the steps [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/Usage) thoroughly.

Here are some tips that led me to success:

- Make sure your android.mk is correct and that you export the NDK_MODULE_PATH.
- Use correctly the following functions

  monstartup("your_lib.so");

  moncleanup();
- If the gmon.out is generated now you need to pull it from the device, but not to anywhere in your PC. For me it only works if I go to the application's folder (where jni, obj, res and other folders are) and I do:

  **console$** adb pull sdcard/gmon.out
- Then run gprof. Try will all the versions in your NDK toolchains. For me only one worked, this one:

  **console$** ~/Libraries/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gprof obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libxxxx.so > profile.txt

Comment: Unfortunately, [android-ndk-profiler](https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler) was discontinued and it's developer discouraged, under other because of Android and/or Devices putting limits on data-transfer (causing huge slow-down of profiler's trace saving).

Comment: But [shiny-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/shinyprofiler/) seems discontinued as well, and if I had to pick which one to bring back to life, I would pick `android-ndk-profiler`, because android-ndk-profiler uses a GCC trick to run it's code at begin of each function automatically (while `shiny-profiler` needs manually adding macro to each function).

Answer (score 8):

The [Shiny profiler](http://code.google.com/p/shinyprofiler/) is platform independent, it runs anywhere and it does not have any dependencies besides a standard C++ compiler. In its more simple usage, all you need to do is add a macro at the beginning of all functions and methods (or at least those that you want to profile).

Comment: Modifying every function in the project is painful. I'd prefer automatic instrumentation. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: If nothing else works, I guarantee you Shiny will. I had a similar problem with webOS. The gprof support was broken, and nothing else was available. Shiny did really well and helped me solve my performance issues. For the effort of instrumenting the code I just wrote a script that located all the function bodies using a regular expression, then inserted the macro call automatically, so it was not painful at all. Good luck with your search.

Comment: Makes sense! Automatic macro insertion, I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any documentation/usage example?

Comment: Seems [shiny-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/shinyprofiler/) is discontinued, but that needed a macro at begin of each function anyway, while [android-ndk-profiler](https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler) uses a GCC trick to run it's code at begin of each function automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Intel VTune Amplifier. This profiler allows you to collect hotspots with stacks on **Android** devices without root or any OS modification. 
Here is simple guide:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-vtune-amplifier-on-non-rooted-android-devices

Comment: About time they start targeting Android. But do they support ARM, or just x86?

Comment: Hi Ilya! :) Is it actually better than android-ndk-profiler? How much does it cost?

Comment: As I know, android-ndk-profiler requires to link your code with theirs lib. You could to try trial version. https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-system-studio

Comment: VTune doesn't support 64bit arm. On my 32bit arm Samsung devices, a samsung security monitor jumps in and stops it from working. I have not been able to get a profile run out of vtune for android.

Answer (score 1):

In the NDK r13b there is a new tool called [simpleperf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/README.md)

Comment: Simpleperf documented at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/README.md